# Why is the EXT3 FS size much smaller vs. partition size?

Tags: size, ext3

We have a partition, which is exactly 50 GByte sized:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
#
```

And we have an EXT3 FS on it, which in 100% filling up the partition, so the partition doesn't have any free.

But the EXT3 FS size (not the free space) is much smaller than the partition size:

```
# df -m /myFS
Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb           50141  5936     41645  13% /myFS
```

50141/1024 is just 48,9 GBytes.

**The big question:** Where did the (51200 - 50141) **1059 MBytes go**?

Already thinked about it:

There are 242131 inodes, maybe that consumes 1059 MBytes? But we are talking about the FS size, not the available space in the FS. inodes could take free space, but not the filesystem size.

```
# df -i /myFS
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       3342336 242131 3100205    8% /myFS
#
```

And yes, as said, FS is at 100% of the partition (disk itself):

```
# resize2fs /dev/sdb
resize2fs 1.42.11 (09-Jul-2014)
The filesystem is already 13107200 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
#
```

And yes, the "/etc/mke2fs.conf" is the default, what a SLES12.3 gives.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're running `df` under root? By default `mke2fs` allocates some of its blocks to the root user and those blocks will **not** be counted as free when you're running `df` from a normal user account. From the `man` page: *-m reserved-blocks-percentage Specify  the percentage of the filesystem blocks reserved for the super-user.  This avoids fragmentation, and allows root-owned daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to function correctly after non-privileged processes are prevented from writing to the filesystem.  The default percentage is 5%.* Maybe it's 10% for SLES.

Comment: I would say - do same experiment with other types... If I have to bet - journaling eats that space... Ext4 has different addressing, on the other hand - by default only metadata are journaled. Interesting question!

Comment: See here: https://askubuntu.com/a/48511/8500